# Saving a collection of objects with BookSleeve

Tags: booksleeve

I am new to both Redis and BookSleeve. I am evaluating whether I should use BookSleeve or ServiceStack.Redis.

ServiceStack seems much more staightforward but I like the idea of pipelining provided by BookSleeve.

I have Redis and BookSleeve running and getting and setting strings is a snap but I'm struggling to find examples of setting and getting a collection of objects such as my pocos.

```
public class MyType
{
....
}

IEnumerable<MyType> types = ....
```

How do I get and set these using BookSleeve?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 since you managed to elicit exactly two answers form the creators of the two products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ServiceStack.Redis it's just a matter of:

```
var redisClient = new RedisClient();
redisClient.StoreAll(myTypes);
```

Not sure what **pipelining** features you're looking for but you can create custom pipelined operations with [ServiceStack.Redis's transactions API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions) (which are always pipelined) or if you don't want the operations to execute within a transaction you can use `Redis.CreatePipeline()` - see these [tests for some examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineCommonTests.cs).

Comment: Thank you. Now I know why there are more examples in the wild with ServiceStack.Redis and why it seems to be more widely adopted. I think it is a better fit for what I want to do.

Answer (score 5):

BookSleeve exposes APIs to read/write strings and blobs (byte[]), but it does not force you down any particular serialization route, or dictate whether a collection should be stored as a single value, vs a list, etc.

Basically, with BookSleeve you would serialize separately, via any serializer that you fancy (XML, json, protobuf, whatever), and send *that*. This is usually only about 2 or 3 lines of code (often involving MemoryStream).

Comment: I see... I was hoping it would offer a little more refinement than that.

Comment: @Refinement that is like saying a coffee machine isn't refined because it doesn't keep your lettuce cold :) it isn't a serialization lib...